# Access - Find string within a record and then goto that record

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've got an Access application that uses a UID for each record, however it does not match up to the record order in SQL.  (i.e. my UID of 12845 corresponds to record number 12834 in Access)

I have a search box that I've created that is supposed to search the Access DB and pull up the record that it finds the matching UID, however, the way I've written the code is that it's going to the Record number that matches the UID (so it will goto record number 12845 instead of record 12834 using UID 12845).

I've been sitting on this for a few days and I can't find a way around it.  Searching the internet has not proved helpful.  IF anyone has an idea for how one can match a string and goto THAT record vs trying to parse the record info myself, then that would be great.

The following is an example of the code I am using. It takes a date string and looks for the string in the records, gets the UID, and then tries to goto the corresponding record:

```
Private Sub FindBarCodeDate_Click()
Dim Barcode As String
Dim EndDate As String

If IsNull(BarcodeSearch.Value) Then
    If IsNull(DateSearch.Value) Then
        GoTo Done
    Else
        EndDate = DateSearch.Value
    End If
Else
    If IsNull(DateSearch.Value) Then
        Barcode = BarcodeSearch.Value
    Else
        Barcode = BarcodeSearch.Value
        EndDate = DateSearch.Value
    End If
End If

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSql As String
Dim TSD As String

If Barcode <> "" Then
    If EndDate <> "" Then
        strSql = "SELECT [TSD ID] FROM dbo_barAdultCollectionData WHERE Barcode = '" & Barcode & "' AND [End Date] = '" & EndDate & "'"
        On Error GoTo Done
        rs.Open strSql, CurrentProject.Connection
        TSD = rs.Fields.Item(0)
        rs.Close
        DoCmd.FindRecord TSD, acEntire, False, acSearchAll, False, acAll, True
        Set rs = Nothing
    Else
        strSql = "SELECT [TSD ID] FROM dbo_barAdultCollectionData WHERE Barcode = '" & Barcode & "'"
        On Error GoTo Done
        rs.Open strSql, CurrentProject.Connection
        TSD = rs.Fields.Item(0)
        rs.Close
        DoCmd.FindRecord FindWhat:=TSD, Match:=acEntire, MatchCase:=False, Search:=acSearchAll, SearchAsFormatted:=False, OnlyCurrentField:=acAll, FindFirst:=True
        Set rs = Nothing
    End If
ElseIf Barcode = "" Then
    If EndDate <> "" Then
        strSql = "SELECT [TSD ID] FROM dbo_barAdultCollectionData WHERE [End Date] = '" & EndDate & "'"
        On Error GoTo Done
        rs.Open strSql, CurrentProject.Connection
        TSD = rs.Fields.Item(0)
        rs.Close
        DoCmd.FindRecord FindWhat:=TSD, Match:=acEntire, MatchCase:=False, Search:=acSearchAll, SearchAsFormatted:=False, OnlyCurrentField:=acAll, FindFirst:=True
        Set rs = Nothing
    End If
Else
Done:
    SearchError.Caption = "Invalid Search Term!"
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Wow an else block that can only be reached by jumping to the label. Not sure I've ever seen that before. Can't imagine it would ever be advisable.

Comment: So you're finding the ID in the SQL table and searching for that ID in the Access table when the ID's are not actually the same. I'm confused as to how you expect it to translate from the SQL ID to the Access ID. Let's back up. In English, if we were to do it manually looking at the tables printed out, how would we know which Access record goes with a given SQL record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `DoCmd.FindRecord`. Use the technique shown in the second example of [Form.RecordsetClone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835062.aspx), e.g.

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset 

Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
rst.FindFirst "yourUIDcolumn = '" & TSD & "'"
If rst.NoMatch Then 
    ' This should not happen
    MsgBox "Record not found", vbCritical, "Panic!"
Else 
    ' Set current record in form to found record
    Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark 
End If 
rst.Close
```

Answer (score 1):

First, try adding -11 to the UID:

```
TSD = CStr(Val(rs.Fields.Item(0).Value) - 11)
```

Also, you need to format your date values as string expressions:

```
EndDate = Format(DateSearch.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
```

and then:

```
strSql = "SELECT [TSD ID] FROM dbo_barAdultCollectionData WHERE [End Date] = #" & EndDate & "#"
```

Comment: What is the basis for your "adding 1" suggestion? Even as a hack I can't see why it would work. If you are trying to hack this specific record example, the difference is 11. But using 11 is still a really dangerous hack.

Comment: Thanks. I missed 10. Corrected now. Dangerous? Indeed - data has to be consistent for this to work. I think I would add a field with the foreign UID, then update this where possible.

Comment: Definitely should be linking on a foreign key field. One more thing. I'm pretty sure you need to subtract not add. We are converting SQL ID to Access ID and the latter is smaller.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff: You may be right. I'll leave that for the questioneer to change ...

Comment: Originally the SQL DB had the exact amount of records that each UID corresponded to.  (i.e. Row 1 had the UID of 1, 2 of 2, etc..).  Someone has deleted some records along the way which has left an imbalance.  As I stated Row 12834 in the SQL table now corresponds to UID 12845. 

In Access, the UID is displayed on each record which is how we wanted the search to work; find criteria, get the UID, then goto the access record that matches that UID. Obviously instead it's going to the Record number of whatever the UID is instead of going to the record containing the UID.

Comment: Then it sounds as @MarkBalhoff is right. I've changed `+` to `-` for you.